# The covariance matrix $\mathbf{C}$: Why does $\ln \text{det} \mathbf{C}=\text{Tr}\ln \mathbf{C}$ hold?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, linear-algebra, trace

Prof. Max Tegmark first introduced the Fisher information matrix into cosmology in his paper titled [Karhunen-Loeve eigenvalue problems in cosmology: How should we tackle large data sets?](https://dx.doi.org/10.1086/303939)

As I read the paper, I noticed that Max utilized the following formula in deriving the Fisher matrix for the Gaussian case:

$$
\ln \text{det} \mathbf{C}=\text{Tr}\ln \mathbf{C},
$$

in which $\mathbf{C}$ is the covariance matrix, defined as
$$
\mathbf{C} = \langle(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})^t\rangle,
$$
where $\mathbf{x}=\{x_0, x_1, x_2,\ldots\}$ is data, and $\mathbf{\mu}$ is the mean of data.

I don't understand at all why $\ln \text{det} \mathbf{C}=\text{Tr}\ln \mathbf{C}$ holds, and I haven't found any sources related to it. So how to derive this formula?
[image]

Comment: This is a question about math, not physics.

Comment: Hint: Diagonalize $\mathbf C$.

Comment: If it isn't already clear from the other comments: the identity is more generally true, not just for the covariance matrix.

Comment: @KBDave Yes, thank you so much!